# Base URL in Kohana 3

Tags: php, kohana-3

How do I get the base URL in Kohana 3?

Is there a solution in raw PHP?

Answer (score 9):

In Kohana it's

```
echo url::base();
```

http://docs.kohanaphp.com/helpers/url

---

In raw PHP

```
echo "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/NameOfApp";
```

Answer (score 7):

For Kohana 3, it's **URL::base()**.

From the doc:

```
// Absolute URL path with no host or protocol
echo URL::base();

// Absolute URL path with host, https protocol and index.php if set
echo URL::base('https', TRUE);

// Absolute URL path with host and protocol from $request
echo URL::base($request);
```

Ref.: http://kohanaframework.org/3.1/guide/api/URL

Answer (score 4):

If you're worried about lots of `url::base()` calls, you can turn it into a constant.

```
define('PATH_BASE', url::base());
```

Answer (score 2):

I am using this, and it works.

```
echo URL::base();
or 
echo URL::base(true);
```